# Highlight/select on text with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, css, text, highlight

I would imagine that this is a very basic question. But I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

I have a heading on multiple lines, with a line-height that I like. But when I highlight/select the text, the bottom of some characters (j, g, y) are hidden. Please see attached image.

[image]

How can I solve it without changing the line-height?

Best regards
Jesper

Comment: Maybe add some gap in css `gap: 10%`

Comment: Not sure that is actually possible. The browser "paints" a background color behind each selected line, and the underlengths of those letters simply get covered by the color from the next line. Not sure that is it an actual issue of such gravity, that it would need fixing to begin with though.

Comment: would be interesting to see an actual working (minimalistic) code for that